# How to resolve a NoClassDefFoundError when working with class files

Tags: java, import, classpath, package

I am still trying to learn Java and decided to take it 1 step further and attempt to use external class files to store data structures (like the header files in C). I keep running into NoClassDefFoundError and would like some methods or techniques that can show me what is going wrong (and where) as the message is not very clear to me :(

I have my directory structure set up as follows:

```
tarskin@5-PARA-11-0120:~/programming/Java/FindGlycopeps$ ls
Default.mzML  FindGlycopeps.class  FindGlycopeps.java  glycoproteomics
tarskin@5-PARA-11-0120:~/programming/Java/FindGlycopeps$ ls glycoproteomics/
Spectrum.class  Spectrum.java
```

The 'main' program is coded as follows:

```
package glycoproteomics;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class FindGlycopeps {

public static LinkedList outside_tag_reader (String filename, String tag) {
        LinkedList<String> someList = new LinkedList<String>();
        DataInputStream in = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(filename);
        in = new DataInputStream(input);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line;
        String regexp = "<"+tag+">(.*)</"+tag+">";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                String buffer = matcher.group(1);
                someList.add(buffer);
            }
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception x) {
        System.err.println(x);
    }
    return(someList);
}

public static void main (String [ ] args) {
    LinkedList<String> binary = new LinkedList<String>();
    ArrayList<Spectrum> spectra = new ArrayList<Spectrum>();
    String file = args[0];
    if (file != null) {
        binary = FindGlycopeps.outside_tag_reader(file,"binary");
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < binary.size(); i++) {
            String buffer = binary.get(i);
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                spectra.add(j, new Spectrum());
                spectra.get(j).mzList.add(buffer);
            } else {
                spectra.get(j).intList.add(buffer);
            }
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println(spectra.get(1).mzList); // purely for testing

        } else {
            System.out.println("No file was specified");
        }
    }
}
```

The 'Data structure' is coded as follows:

```
package glycoproteomics;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Spectrum implements Comparable<Spectrum>{
   float precursor;
   ArrayList<String> mzList;
   ArrayList<String> intList;

   public int compareTo(Spectrum arg0) {
      return 0;
   }
}
```

I have compiled both .java files with just javac  and been attemping to run the main class, from the 'root' using several variations of java -classpath (also tried -cp) ./://Java/FindGlycopeps/glycoproteomics FindGlycopeps and it keeps giving errors such as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: FindGlycopeps (wrong name: glycoproteomics/FindGlycopeps)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: FindGlycopeps. Program will exit.
```

What would be good ways to figure out how it is going wrong and what should be changed in my 'thinking'? I would appreciate an explanation why something should be done instead of 'do this to fix it' if possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java class files must be in a directory with the same name as the package. So you need to add `~/programming/Java/FindGlycopeps` to your classpath (and not `~/programming/Java/FindGlycopeps/glycoproteomics`) and the file `FindGlycopeps.class` must be in `~/programming/Java/FindGlycopeps/glycoproteomics` (instead of `~/programming/Java/FindGlycopeps`)

Comment: The 'main' program also goes into the package folder, ok. You should be able to run the program by simply saying 'java FindGlycopeps' from within the package directory since the classpath is the current directory if not set right?

Comment: Maybe. Frankly, I've never tried to run Java without a proper classpath. Try `-classpath .` or `-classpath "$PWD"`

Answer (score 1):

The file `FindGlycopeps.class` needs to be in the directory `glycoproteomics`. Package structure is mirrored by the directory structure on the file system.